# unitTests.returnDefaultValues works when run in gradlew but not in Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, gradle

I have a test

```
class MyClassTest{
    @Test
    fun testing() {
        Log.d("", "")
    }
}
```

By default it will fail as `Log` is not mocked. However, in order to have it through, we could set

```
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
```

We could run the test smoothly, and through using `./gradlew test` in console.

However, when I run on Android Studio (i.e. RightClick on the `MyClassTest`, and select `Run 'MyClassTest'`, it still errors out stating

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method d in android.util.Log not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
```

Do I need to do anything in Android Studio to have that test run and take into consideration the `testOptions` set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time run in Android Studio, I do the below.

RightClick on the MyClassTest, and select Run `MyClassTest`, it will produce a test run configuration that has setting `Gradle-aware Make` in the `Before-launch` setting.

This will cause the above problem. To fix this issue, change the configuration by removing `Gradle-aware Make` and instead add `Build`.

Now then run the test configuration, all will work.